# Using 'Click at' result or control click in Applescript

Tags: macos, click, applescript

I am trying to write an Applescript to recover metadata from my (thousands) of photos on Flickr (and copy the meta data to the same photos in Apple Photos).

I am aware Flickr has API for doing things like this, but I found the Flickr API rather complex to use, requires authentication for non-public photos and the results need processing for interfacing with Apple Photos.

My approach is therefore to interact with the Flickr organize user interface to edit individual photos and mimic what I can do manually. This means clicking on various elements in the Flickr Edit photo panel of https://www.flickr.com/photos/organize (with specified bounds for the window, so the elements to click are always in the same place).

My script at present is:

```
copy my getMyName() to myName

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    -- Assume Safari is on the Flickr page www.flickr.com/photos/organize and has the edit panel for one photo open.
    display dialog myName & return & return & "Read the photo metadata" buttons {"OK"}
    if name of window 1 ≠ "Flickr: Organize your photos & videos" then
        display dialog myName & return & return & "Name of window not 'Flickr: Organize your photos & videos'" buttons {"Quit " & myName}
    else if URL of document 1 ≠ "https://www.flickr.com/photos/organize" then
        display dialog myName & return & return & "URL of document not 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/organize'" buttons {"Quit " & myName} default button 2
    else
        if bounds of window 1 ≠ {0, 23, 1267, 789} then
            set bounds of window 1 to {0, 23, 1267, 789} -- 'normalise' window size
        end if
        delay 2
        tell application "System Events"
            click at {400, 225} -- Title, Description & Tags
            delay 7 -- the click takes some time!
            click at {500, 275} -- Title  (In Title, Description & Tags)
            delay 7 -- the click takes some time!
            keystroke "c" using command down -- copy
            delay 2
            set theTitle to the clipboard as text
            click at {500, 375} -- Description (In Title, Description & Tags)
            delay 7 -- the click takes some time!
            keystroke "a" using command down -- select all Description
            delay 2
            keystroke "c" using command down -- copy
            delay 2
            set theDescription to the clipboard as text
            click at {500, 467} -- Tags  (In Title, Description & Tags)
            delay 7 -- the click takes some time!
            keystroke "a" using command down -- select all Description
            delay 2
            keystroke "c" using command down -- copy
            delay 2
            set theTags to the clipboard as text
            display dialog "SafariScript1" & return & return & "Title: " & theTitle & return & "Description: " & theDescription & return & "Tags: " & theTags buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2

        end tell
    end if
end tell

on getMyName()
    set myPath to path to me as text
    if myPath ends with ":" then
        set n to -2
    else
        set n to -1
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    set myName to text item n of myPath
    if (myName contains ".") then
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
        set myName to text 1 thru text item -2 of myName
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return myName
end getMyName
```

I would like to insert a check that the photo Edit panel is open, before the line

```
tell application "System Events"
```

The Applescript code

```
click at {325, 225}
```

clicks at the position of the text "Edit: " in the Edit Photo panel, and produces the result.

```
static text "Edit: " of group 19 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Flickr: Organize your photos & videos" of application process "Safari" of application "System Events"
```

But I can't figure out how to check this is correct result - any suggestions?

Alternatively (and perhaps more simply), manually control clicking on the word "Edit" selects it, and it would then be possible to use

```
keystroke "c" using command down -- copy
```

to copy this and check it is the word "Edit". But I can't find a way to do a control click in AppleScript. Any suggestions?

**Update 12 Feb 2017**

If found that to check for the static text "Edit" I could use

```
if (click at {325, 225}) = static text "Edit: " of group 25 of UI element 1 ¬
    of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window ¬
    "Flickr: Organize your photos & videos" of application process "Safari" then
```

This seems to work fine, except that from time to time the group number after  "Edit: " changes (presumably because Flickr have changed their code for the page). In the last few days the group number has changed from 19 to 20 to 25. This is a bit a pain as I have to update the script, but I can live with it.

I have a similar issue with the group number changing in the Applescript I am using to make sure the 'Go to next item when you save?' checkbox of the Edit panel is set.

```
tell checkbox 1 of group 31 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 ¬
    of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 ¬
    of window "Flickr: Organize your photos & videos" ¬
    of application process "Safari"
    if not (its value as boolean) then click it
        delay theDelay -- the click takes some time!        
    end tell
```

I now have an AppleScript that works (as long as I keep updating the group numbers).

**Further update 12 Feb 2017**

Found a way to ignore changes to the group numbers. A **click at {x, y}** gives the path to the UI element at {x, y}. This can be copied into a variable. The variable can then used to access the attributes of the UI element. So for the Flickr edit panel on the Flickr page I am interested in, to check the panel is open a check can be made for  static text "Edit: " at the right place without needing to know the group number by:

```
copy (click at {325, 225}) to UIelement
if (class of UIelement = static text) and (((value of UIelement) as text) = "Edit: ") then
```

Similarly, to make sure 'Go to next item when you save?' checkbox is set:

```
copy (click at {453, 541}) to checkboxGotoNext
tell checkboxGotoNext
    if not (its value as boolean) then click it
    delay theDelay -- the click takes some time!        
end tell
```

Comment: Further to my original post, I found that I could just write